# How to deploy an Laravel 5.4 API and Vue.js 2 project?

Tags: javascript, laravel, rest, api, vue.js

I have created an API using Laravel 5.4 and frontend side using Vue.js 2 on different domains. Installed CORS to an API. By this time it all works correctly in my local machine. How should I deploy it in a proper way to a hosting server? I have 2 folders: **backend** and **frontend**. In there I've implemented 2 separate projects: one is an API and the other one is a frontend side.

Here's my **routes/api.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth']], function() {    
    Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    Route::get('/requests', 'RequestController@index');
    Route::delete('/requests/{id}', 'RequestController@destroy');
});

Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');


Route::post('/requests', 'RequestController@create');

Route::get('/', function() {
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true
    ]);
});

Route::get('/hello', function() {
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'API is working correctly.'
    ]);
});
```

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do ?

Comment: @AnarBayramov I'm trying to join the projects into one and share it to production in a hosting server. Could u please help with that?

Comment: Please don't double post questions.   I would suggest that you remove the first question from an hour ago.

Comment: @skribe I have tried a lot to share but noone can help me with that...

Comment: I understand.  It happens to all of us sometimes that a question takes a long time to get an answer.  Keep editing and adding to your question as you research the problem yourself and it will bump it to the top a bit to help keep it alive.

Comment: @skribe I deleted the previous question as you requested.

Comment: P.S.  Not trying to be critical or troll you just trying to be helpful :)   I think we are still feeling a little unclear where the difficulty lies.  Have you tried something and are getting an error,  or you just don't know where to get started?

Comment: @skribe I have a lot before posting a question) last post was a part of my job that has been done. Thank u for ur help anyway

Comment: This question really depends on which hosting service you intend to use and the hosting service will probably provide instructions on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have already observed that Laravel comes pre configured to use Vue.js as its frontend, which you use to build components and then build or compile into your app.js using Webpack, Laravel-Mix, Babel etc.

The normal structure is your Laravel code, your api, lives in the `app` directory, and your Vue.js and style sheets are built in the `resources/assets/` directory, then built out into your public html directory using `npm run dev` or `npm run watch` etc.

To connect your front end and backend,  or communicate between the two, you would use some form of  XMLHttpRequest, a.k.a Ajax.

Laravel has Axios installed by default for all your Ajax needs. This is where you want to start looking at making the api calls to your backend.

An Axios request from Vue looks something like this. (promise based)

```
axios.get('logout').then(//some function).catch(//some function);
```

Here is a simple api request being made to remote endpoint that returns a json response with `{"message":"hello world"}`

```js
Vue.component('example', {
 template: '#cool',
  data(){
   return{
      requestData: {"message":"waiting for request..."},
    }
  },
  methods: {
    makeRequest(){
      axios.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/xpk6h').then(function(response) {
          console.log(response.data.message); 
          this.requestData = response.data;
       }.bind(this));
    }
  },
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <example></example>
</div>


<template id="cool" functional>
      <div>
          <button @click="makeRequest">make api request</button>
          <p>{{requestData.message}}</p>
      </div>
 </template>
```

Comment: I know that Vue comes out of the box with Laravel. But what if I will need to implement ReactJS app and Laravel as a backend?

Comment: You would go about it in the same way.  Whether you are using Vue, React, or Angular,  your build the front end more or less independently of the backend framework.   Then make requests using a ajax library of some sort like Axios.

Comment: Did this help? Would a working example of the front end connected to an api help?

Comment: Ok just added a simple working example of Vue and axios making a request to an api.   Let me know what you don't understand if anything.

Comment: P.S.  Be patient when clicking the button as the api service I am using is rather slow.  It takes about 5 seconds or so for the response.

Comment: I have solved the problem. This link helped me: https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-time-tracker-with-laravel-5-and-angularjs-part-2#setting-up-the-api

Comment: Thank u so much for spending your time and trying to help me! I really appreciate it

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer help at all in pointing you in the right direction, I would appreciate if you marked it as the accepted answer.